# Build .NET Core 3.1.1 from git repository

Tags: coreclr

I would like to build from source the .NET Core 3.1 CLR and libraries. I checked out the latest from https://github.com/dotnet/runtime. Running the build scripts will produce the next version of .net and not 3.1.1. Can you tell me how to get the .NET Core 3.1.1 source and build it? I want to be able to produce a debug version of the core so that I can add tracing and logging.

Answer (score 0):

Go to 3.1.1 tag in dotnet/coreclr repo (https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/tree/v3.1.1)
The entire coreclr repo has merged (along with corefx, corert and the installer) to dotnet/runtime.
The dotnet/coreclr repo is an archive currently, which still holds all the old tags.